# Scroll height adjustment with infinity scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At the moment when 'scroll' is at the very bottom, the function `getUsers ()` is called. How to set the scroll so that it doesn't reach the end of the slider, and the `getUsers ()` function is called. That there would be an infinity scroll effect. I mean the scroll effect like here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ww7npwxokk. When the scroll reaches the bottom, it goes back.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nq8btq

```
import './style.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      page: 1
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers = () => {
    axios({
      url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`,
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => { 
      this.setState({
        users: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }) 
  }

  scroll = (e) => {
    const page = this.state.page;
    const bottom = e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop === e.target.clientHeight;
    if (bottom) { 
      alert('bottom');
      this.getUsers()

      this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1
      })
    }

    const top = e.target.scrollTop; 

     if(top === 0 && page > 1) {
        alert('I AM AT THE TOP');

         this.setState({
          page: this.state.page - 1
        })
      }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.page)
     console.log(this.state.users)
    return (
      <div>
         <div onScroll={this.scroll} className="container">
            <ul>
              {this.state.users.map((user, index) => 
                <li>
                  {user.name}
                </li>   
              )}
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I've updated your code, slightly simplified, but mostly your code with the key points commented.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    page: 1
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers = () => {
    axios({
      url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`,
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => { 
      this.setState({
        // *you must append to users in state, otherwise 
        // the list will not grow as the user scrolls
        users: [...this.state.users, ...res.data],
        page: this.state.page + 1
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }) 
  }

  scroll = (e) => {
    // *simplified, to only handle appending to the list
    // note the 50px from the bottom, adjust as required
    // so that the request is made before the users reaches
    // the bottom of the page under normal scrolling conditions.  
    if (e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop <= e.target.clientHeight + 50) { 
      this.getUsers();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onScroll={this.scroll} className="container">
        <ul>
          {this.state.users.map((user, index) =>
            // *always add a unique key for each item
            <li key={user.name}>
              {user.name}
            </li>   
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be setting state using `page: this.state.page + 1`. You should use the setState function which takes prevState.

Comment: @JonathanMiles And such an infinity scroll should work like pagination? In pagination, when I click 1, it charges me, e.g. 10 users, I click 2, it charges me, 10 users (the table always has 10 users). And in infinity scroll gets 10, then adds 10 (the array is constantly increasing). how should it work?

Comment: @Umbro It really depends on what you want to achieve, what you are referring to is actually virtualisation and not infinite scroll.  You can have infinite scroll with, or without, virtualisation.  With virtualisation is slightly harder to implement and outside of the scope of your original question.

Comment: Shouldn't the if condition be inverse? Otherwise, on even minute changes in scroll position would trigger the call.

Comment: @kooskoos Have you tested it yourself, I wrote this code on a train but I tested it and it works.  If you watch the network tab you will see that it works exactly as I stated.  It does initiate the first additional fetch almost as soon as the users scrolls but that's because the scroll bar is initially almost full height.  If you then continue to scroll you will see a new request only when the scroll reaches -50px from the bottom.

Granted the logic seems backwards, even my original initial implementation was `- 50` and screwed with my head but then your logic is inverted to start with.

Comment: @JonathanMiles Yes, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is decide when to call get users.

i.e. if you want it to be called when you have already scrolled through 70% the height then the factor would be 0.3 (30%)

Whenever the scroll exceeds the 70% mark `this.getusers()` would be called.

Check out how I have modified the same condition written by you.

Rest of the code remains the same

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      page: 1
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers = () => {
    axios({
      url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`,
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => { 
      this.setState({
        users: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }) 
  }

  scroll = (e) => {
    const page = this.state.page;
    const bottom = e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop < e.target.clientHeight-0.3*e.target.clientHeight;
    if (bottom) { 
      alert('bottom');
      this.getUsers()

      this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1
      })
    }

    const top = e.target.scrollTop; 

     if(top === 0 && page > 1) {
        alert('I AM AT THE TOP');

         this.setState({
          page: this.state.page - 1
        })
      }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.page)
     console.log(this.state.users)
    return (
      <div>
         <div onScroll={this.scroll} className="container">
            <ul>
              {this.state.users.map((user, index) => 
                <li>
                  {user.name}
                </li>   
              )}
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't provide infinity scroll, have you tried it yourself... it still stops at the end and although the results may update you are not providing scroll functionality here which was question asks about.

Comment: @kooskoos And such an infinity scroll should work like pagination? In pagination, when I click 1, it charges me, e.g. 10 users, I click 2, it charges me, 10 users (the table always has 10 users). And in infinity scroll gets 10, then adds 10 (the array is constantly increasing). how should it work?

Comment: @JonathanMiles check out https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-framework-ks21e. It seems to work just fine

Comment: @Umbro I think pagination is better in your use case as it gives a visual cue to the person using it clarifying how many users are there. i.e if I am on page 3 I already know I have already gone through 30 users. Whereas in case of just infinite scroll I have no idea how many users are there and it will be very hard for me to go to a user I have already seen. i.e In case of pagination I know user  "xyz" was on page 3.

Comment: @kooskoos The link you posted works just fine but that's not the code you have in you answer.  In fact it implements exactly what I describes in my answer.

Comment: Yes, all I wanted to explain was you can use percentage based approach to decide when to make the call.

Comment: @kooskoos I don't believe the question was how to do maths, I'm sure the poster could have worked out how to calculate 70% of the height.  If you see my answers already provides a detailed explanation of the scroll function.

Also, your approach is interesting.

    `e.target.clientHeight-0.3*e.target.clientHeight`

it can be simplified as such
     `e.target.clientHeight * 0.7`

Answer (score 1):

This [lib](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller) should do the trick for you

```
$ yarn add react-infinite-scroller
```

Very simple to implement

```
<InfiniteScroll
  pageStart={0}
  loadMore={this.getUsers()}
  hasMore={this.state.hasMoreUsers}
  loader={<div key={0}>loading ...</div>}
> 
  <li>
    {user.name}
  </li>
</InfiniteScroll>
```

Don't forget to import the lib in your component file

```
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
```

Comment: Can you create your example with my example dates?